# Travel.SE meet up/group expedition?

Tags: discussion

I'm not entirely sure what I want to suggest here... But it occurs to me that we have a nice community of travelers here, some with lots of experience, some with little to no experience.  But we all have a common interest in traveling.

One of the things I enjoy about traveling is the opportunity to meet other travelers while I'm traveling.  On buses, in air ports, in hostels...

So the thought occurred to me:  It might be interesting to network with others on this site, either while traveling, or on a group expedition. Especially in the context of the personal (if not superficial) relationships that are often built on this site.

Is there interest in this sort of idea?  If so, how can it be facilitated?

Comment: Maybe for now a list of users and their home cities?  We could make a subreddit for this as well, or a facebook group?

Comment: Vancouver, FTW! :)

Comment: I think I like the Facebook group idea. (As much as I hate Facebook).

Comment: I'm up for it...

Comment: Great Idea.....

Comment: would also support that

Comment: Based on some recent questions, I think Vancouver's looking like a good spot for a meetup later this month!

Comment: 18/19 August in Vancouver would be great ;)

Comment: Sadly I'll be down south in Seattle those days. Maybe you could meet Mark that week, and I'll get him a beer the next one! One for the FB group probably though...

Comment: +1 Vancouver (or Vancouver Island)

Comment: Well saw @Gagravarr last week, so 18/19 August could certainly work :)

Answer (score 3):

I have created a new [Facebook group](http://www.facebook.com/groups/118962814909394/) for this purpose.  If we decide some other medium is better in the future, we can always abandon the FB group.

Please join the group if you're interested in meeting other Travel.SE members as you or they travel.